# What's the best way to store and access XML in Android?

Tags: xml, android, resources, assets

While I realize resources themselves are defined in XML files, if I have an XML file of my own type that I wish to use, should I be storing them in "res/xml"?

Is there a better way to do this such as using assets and then loading them as binary to be parsed by another XML library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with adding the XML resource inside the `res` folder with the specific resource type. Its a convention that I have adapted to, having all my files in the same directory for organization.

If you add your XML file inside of `res/xml` it can be accessed anytime at run-time via [**`Resources.getXML()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml%28int%29)

Comment: Do you know which API I'll end up using when loading XML through Resource?

Comment: I am kind of confused what you mean by which API, can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: What type of parser is used?  Is there an Android API reference?  More simply, what type of object does Resources.getXML() return?

Comment: It returns back an `XmlResourceParser` from the Android API

Comment: Also parsing XML files with the XmlPullParser returned by Resources.getXml() is 10x-100x faster than parsing a raw file, since the built tools preprocess the XML file into a binary representation.

Comment: Not bad!  Good to get that noted, I'll make special efforts to continue with this.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer ease of coding over lightning fast speed then I would use the [Simple XML library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) instead. It is just easier to program for. I wrote a blog post that you can view that explains [how to include it in a project](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/) of yours.

Answer (score 0):

**First knowing how to correctly Access Files in Android:**

You might need access your original files and directories. If you do, then saving your files in `res/` won't work for you, because the `only way to read a resource from res/ is with the resource ID`. Instead, you can save your resources in the assets/ directory.

Files saved in the assets/ directory are not given a resource ID, so you can't reference them through the R class or from XML resources. Instead, you can query files in the assets/ directory like a normal file system and read raw data using AssetManager.

However, if all you require is the ability to read raw data (such as a video or audio file), then save the file in the res/raw/ directory and read a stream of bytes using openRawResource().

**Accessing XML Files**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml

```
res/xml/

Arbitrary XML files that can be read at runtime by calling Resources.getXML()
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

```
Resources res = activity.getResources();
XmlResourceParser xrp = res.getXml(R.xml.the_file_name_aka_resource_ID);
```