# android How to access a file in APK at runtime?

Tags: java, android, apk

Is there a way to package a configuration XML file(e.g., foo.xml) inside APK, and read it at runtime? For web app, you can put anything inside a WAR file, then read them at run time.

After installation, APK file is extracted somewhere. How to get the directory(apkDir) where APK is extracted?

```
   File f = new File(apkDir, "foo.xml");
```

context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir or sourceDir is the location?  It is not clear to me by looking at Javadoc.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396718/whats-the-best-way-to-store-and-access-xml-in-android

Comment: It is for XML files only, and they must be under res/.  It is better to separate those files from android resources, e.g., conf/foo.xml.